# How to apply back-ticks to a vector of .Primitive names

Tags: r

Is there way to apply back-ticks to a vector of `.Primitive` function names so that it can be passed safely to `is.primitive` ?

Currently I use `get(x)` for `x` in `is.primitive(x)`. These first calls,

```
> is.primitive(`$`)
#[1] TRUE
> is.primitive(get("$"))
#[1] TRUE
```

are the right ones.  All the next calls don't work.

```
> is.primitive("$")
#[1] FALSE
## which is a bit confusing considering the argument name in
> `$`
#.Primitive("$")
##----
## other tries ...
> is.primitive($)
#Error: unexpected '$' in "is.primitive($"
> is.primitive("`$`")
#[1] FALSE
> is.primitive(`"$"`)
#Error in is.primitive(`"$"`) : object '"$"' not found
> sQuote("$")
#[1] "‘$’"
> is.primitive(sQuote("$"))
#[1] FALSE
> as.name("$") ## most promising! ...
#`$`
> is.primitive(as.name("$")) ## ...but no
#[1] FALSE
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I'd like to perform some analysis on the objects in `package:base` using something like

```
Vis.primitive <- Vectorize(is.primitive)
```

The vector `x` I'll be using is

```
x <- ls("package:base")
```

Comment: What does your "vector of .Primitive function names" look like?

Comment: @MrFlick, I added that at the bottom.

Comment: You're going to have to do some form a `get` to actually get the function from a character vector of names. `is.primitive` checks if the object assigned to the variable you pass is a primitive function. It doesn't decode the name. That's why `as.name("$")` doesn't work, because that's returns a name object, not a function. You can decode your vector `x` with `Filter(is.primitive, mget(x, as.environment("package:base")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth reading the help for functional programming

(`?Map`/`?Filter`)

This gives examples of how to use `Filter` to perform such analyses.

You could do something like

`Filter(is.primitive,  sapply(ls(baseenv()), get, baseenv()))`

An alternative would be to use `match.fun` to search for the function

eg

`match.fun('$')`

There is no need to mess arround with `` ` ``!

Comment: This is relieving, thank you! I'm only just getting familiar with this group of functions.  Good to know that I got it right though when  called `x[Vectorize(is.primitive)(Vectorize(get)(x))]` :)